# Showing $f(z)=2xy+i(x^2+y^2)$ is defined on all of $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

What does it mean to be defined on all of $\Bbb C$? That is has no points at infinity?

How do I show the below is defined on all of $\Bbb C$?

$$f(z)=2xy+i(x^2+y^2)$$

Is it something to do with continuity or differentiation?

I can easily show it isn't analytic anywhere, is this related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x = \Re(z)$ and $y = \Im(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  These are defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$.  Your function is a polynomial in these, so the composition is defined everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hmmmm, what if it were not a polynomial, such as $e^ye^{ix}$?

Comment: Still, the exponential function is a smooth function on the real line.  Still works.